# How to remove event handler which is dynamically created?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I am relatively newbie. The problem I have is a simple one I think, but I cant find a solution. Clicking on button1 opens a popup and adds to `canvas1` a MouseDown event handler `canvas1.MouseDown += (s1, e1) =>{...};` I want to remove this when the user closes the popup. Here's the whole code:

```
namespace MyfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int linesNumber = 0;

            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Content = "Draw";
            button1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            button1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            button1.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                Popup popup = new Popup();
                popup.PlacementTarget = button1;
                popup.IsOpen = true;

                Button closePopupButton = new Button();
                closePopupButton.Content = "close";
                closePopupButton.Click += (s1, e1) =>
                {
                    popup.IsOpen = false;
                    // remove canvas1.MouseDown event handler here
                };
                popup.Child = closePopupButton;

                canvas1.MouseDown += (s1, e1) =>
                {
                    Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas1);
                    Line line = new Line();
                    line.X2 = point.X; line.Y2 = point.Y;
                    line.Stroke = Brushes.Red; line.StrokeThickness = 1;
                    canvas1.Children.Add(line);
                    linesNumber++;
                };
            };
            grid1.Children.Add(button1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

save the eventhandler somewhere in a variable

```
MouseButtonEventHandler onMousedown = (o, args) => 
{ 
    ...
};

canvas1.MouseDown += onMouseDown;
```

and later you can remove the eventhandler again:

```
canvas1.MouseDown -= onMouseDown;
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, but with MouseButtonEventHandler instead of var

Comment: yes sorry, i also have noticed this mistake and have corrected it

Comment: It looks like @VladimirMarinov was trying to do this in his original question, and I'm trying to do it now: I need to remove the onMousedown event handler from WITHIN the onMouseDown event handler! When I attempt to do that, though, intellisense says "use of unassigned local variable onMouseDown" How did you solve this?

Comment: Ahh! I think I've solved it: if you want to have access to onMousedown from WITHIN onMousedown to unsubscribe it as an event handler, you must simply declare MouseButtonEventHandler onMousedown; BEFORE assigning it, onMouseDown = (o,args) => {//mycodehere};